# Updraftplus for wordpress site on digitalocean give ipaddress for googledrive auth which google wont accept

Tags: php, wordpress, google-drive-api, digital-ocean

I am trying to set up updraftplus for one of my wordpress site on digitalocean droplet.

On updraftplus setting it gives me to add following as the authorised URI on google api.

```
http://123.456.789./wp-admin/options-general.php?action=updraftmethod-googledrive-auth
```

(Obfuscated my ip for security reason).

When I tried to enter it into google api to create a new web application client id Google won't accept it.
So I went ahead and put my domain name in place of ip address and was able to create a client id and secret.

But when I added that into updraftplus settings and try to authenticate then Google drive account wont accept it.
I am getting the following error.

```
 Error: Invalid_request
nvalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Raw IP addresses not allowed:   http://123.456.789/wp-admin/options-general.php?action=updraftmethod-googledrive-auth
```

Request Deatails:

```
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
response_type=code
access_type=offline
redirect_uri=http://123.456.789/wp-admin/options-general.php?action=updraftmethod-     googledrive-auth
approval_prompt=force
state=token
client_id=some-numbers.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

Is there any way to work around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should contact updraftplus  support for help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this.

The problem was in the wordpress setting (in General), WordPress Address(URL) and Site Address(URL) had ip address value instead of site domain name.

So in the URL field it was showing ip address instead of regular wordpress url.

Changing those fields to my domain name fixed the issue.